# Displaying long application name in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, long-integer, titanium-mobile

I'm new to Iphone development. I've developed an application with Titanium Studio, but I have a long name for my application. When I deployed the application to device, I saw that the name was not displayed properly instead it was displayed with dots. Ex. "My long..me" instead of "My long application name".

Is there any way to add a new line character so that I can see the whole name in the device? Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible for the name under the icon (Bundle Display Name).  Some developers put some additional text as part of the icon image.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible. Have you ever seen an iOS app with a two-line name?